# Using WPF controls in a Surface application

Tags: wpf, treeview, wpf-controls, pixelsense

I'm needing a `TreeView` control in our surface application. Situation is ive already created a `TreeView` implementation using infragistics `XamlDataTree`. Im wondering whether this control set can be used in a Surface application (being that it is a WPF app under the hood)?

Question also in general can you reuse standard WPF controls in the surface environment?

Also is there a tool already in the Surface SDK suite that would suit a `TreeView` style layout?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the XamlDataTree, but in general, you can use any WPF control in a [Surface Presentation Layer Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727733.aspx).

Comment: Does it actually work? They render, but I haven't found a single WPF control that you can interact with on the Surface.

Comment: @RyanAmos are you referring to Surface 1 or 2? In Surface 1 you usually had to put WPF controls in a SurfaceContentControl, whereas Surface 2 is simply based on Windows 7 Touch.

Comment: Surface 2. I have used sliders, data grids, text fields (I think it's called textbox or something, but I'm used to the Java name). None of it worked, but when I substituted in the Surface version, it worked.

Comment: That's perhaps why there are the Surface version of these controls. You would certainly never use a Slider in a Surface application when there also is a SurfaceSlider. What i have in mind is that you can generally use any WPF control, since a Surface Presentation Layer Application is a WPF Application. If for example a WPF control handles Windows Touch Manipulations, it behaves perfectly on Surface. Other controls might perhaps be pimped up with [TouchExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957280).

Comment: There is no surface version of the DataGrid, but there are surface versions of Slider and TextBox. I was literally JUST starting with the language and Surface (as in less than 3 days). I remember I could not type in the text box nor slide the slider(Although I could in the simulator). I quickly fixed those, but I have left a DataGrid, as I do not want it to be interactive. As for the XamlDataTree, if it follows my minimal experience, it will have to be "Surface-ized" with TouchExtensions.